# How do i correctly implement jquery-ui accordion in magento cms page

Tags: jquery-ui, magento, content-management-system, accordion

I have search a whole day and try many references but still not solve. What i want to do is apply jquery-ui accordion for a specific cms page in magento 1.9.2.1, using update layout xml. I have put the following code in the update layout xml:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css</stylesheet></action>
   <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js</script>    
   </action>
</reference>
<reference name="header">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var $j = jQuery.noconflict();
       $j(function() {
           $j( ".accordion" ).accordion({
             active: false,
             collapsible: true,
             header: "h3",
             heightStyle: "content"
          });
       });
 </script>
</reference>
```

I did check using page source info and find out that the jquery file and jquery-ui file is loaded in the page. 
I also try in single html page and the accordion is function (refer the source to http://code.jqueryui.com) this multiple accordion is working

```
<div class="accordion">
   <h3>head 1</h3>
   <div>
   .......
   </div>

   <h3>head 2</h3>
   <div>
   .......
   </div>

   <h3>head 3</h3>
   <div>
   .......
   </div>
</div>
......
......
......
<div class="accordion">
   <h3>Other head 1</h3>
   <div>
   .......
   </div>

   <h3>Other head 2</h3>
   <div>
   .......
   </div>

   <h3>Other head 3</h3>
   <div>
   .......
   </div>
</div>
```

but it does not work when the same content and mark up loaded into magento cms page with above code put in update layout xml.

I have tried many suggestion from the standard call like:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
          active: false,
          collapsible: true,
          header: "h3",
          heightStyle: "content"
         });
        });
</script>
```

or some variation to avoid conlflict

Please someone help to get this solved.

Thank you

Bun

Answer (score 0):

Remove your custom script part from xml layout and put right below your accordion html part then, it must work.

Your phtml file

```
<div class="accordion">...</div>
<!--/ Put your script here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $j = jQuery.noconflict();
   $j(function() {
       $j( ".accordion" ).accordion({
         active: false,
         collapsible: true,
         header: "h3",
         heightStyle: "content"
      });
   });
```

Comment: Thank You for your response, i did try your suggestion, but still not functioning.

Comment: as you can see here i copy the loaded page info, the jquery and jquery-ui both are loaded.

Comment: if your jquery & jquery-ui has been loaded. and you can see this custom script being rendered on your page, it must work or you might have missed something. Do you see any errors on console ?

Comment: the jquery-1.10.2.min.js is loaded, jquery-ui.min.js alsoa there jquery.noconflict also loaded, the jquery-ui.css also loaded, custom script also there in the page. but Still not work...little scratch my head...i would like to paste the page source info but it seem too long.

Comment: do use pastebin.com and get me the link.

Comment: here the link of copy from page source info, http://pastebin.com/YfgmynNz   thank you for your help